# Adding hyperlink to image in Indesign with Applescript

Tags: hyperlink, applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create an AppleScript that creates hyperlinks on every linked image in InDesign.

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"
  activate
  tell active document
  set grphicBoxs to all graphics of layer activeLayer
  set myLinks to {}
  repeat with I in grphicBoxs
  set iLink to item link of i
  set end of myLinks to iLink
  end repeat

  repeat with theLinkRef in myLinks
  set theLinkName to ((name of theLinkRef) as string)
  display dialog "theLinkName: " & theLinkName

  set myHyperLink to "www.myURL"
  set myHyperLinkName to "myURL name"

  try
  set hyperLinkPreSet to make hyperlink URL destination with properties `{name:myHyperLinkName, destination URL:myHyperLink}`
  on error
  set hyperLinkPreSet to hyperlink URL destination myHyperLinkName
  end try


  try
  set hyperLinkObject to make hyperlink page item source with properties `{name:myHyperLinkName, source page item:rectangle theLinkName, hidden:false}`
  on error
  set TheHS to hyperlink page item source myHyperLinkName
  end try

  display dialog "hyperLinkObject:" & hyperLinkObject

  make new hyperlink with properties `{destination:myHyperLink, source:hyperLinkObject, visible:false}`


  end repeat

  end tell
end tell
```

The expected result is that the hyperlink preset that is created is applied to the chosen object. But I get this error message.

> Invalid value for parameter 'source' of method 'make'. Expected page
>   item, but received nothing.

Is there anyone here who has successfully created hyperlinks on linked objects who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

set activeLayer to "Layer 1"
set counter to 1

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"
   activate
   tell active document
       set grphicBoxs to all graphics of layer activeLayer
       set myLinks to {}
       repeat with i in grphicBoxs
           set iLink to item link of i
           set end of myLinks to iLink
       end repeat

```
   repeat with theLinkRef in myLinks
       set theLinkName to ((name of theLinkRef) as string)
       set theLinkNameNoext to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in theLinkName) - 1) of theLinkName

       set myHyperLink to "http://macscripter.net"
       set myHyperLinkName to theLinkNameNoext & " " & counter

       make hyperlink with properties {name:myHyperLinkName, source:make hyperlink page item source with properties {source page item:rectangle counter}, destination:make hyperlink URL destination with properties {destination URL:myHyperLink}}

       set counter to counter + 1
   end repeat
```

end tell
end tell